# jQuery - Set var - Multiple Ul's - Target same li child for every ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists

Simple question I hope.

I want to use jQuery to identify identical children in a similar list based setting (the equivalent horizontally.)
Pretend I have this:

```
<ul class="features">

<li class="category"><a href="services_hwrep.html">Hardware Repair</a></li>

***background on hover for both*** 
<li class="category"><a href="services_netts.html">Network Troubleshooting</a></li>
</ul>


<ul class="features">

<li class="category"><a href="services_something_else.html">Hardware Repair</a></li>

***background on hover for both*** 
<li class="category"><a href="services_something_further.html">Network

</ul>
```

And I want the background to change on ALL children of either list item 1 or 2 (horizontal positioning).

Please don't mention tables. Very good reason I'm not using them.

Here is my code thus far for simplicity:

```
<script>
(function() { 

    $('ul.features li').on('hover', function() {

        var $eqTd = <! How to target every equivalent child across both ul's >
        var $blah = <! Whatever else I need >


            <! I Can Figure This Part Out. Need to think about defining the items before I declare a function... >

    });

})();
</script>
```

Wondering at this point. Is there a CSS method? I have a live example so you can see how I want to change BG horizontally here:

http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/price.html

(* Just tried to simplify the code. I can figure out the styling and whatnot.)

NEED TO DEFINE:
Horizontal Li elements

To Change:
BG Color:

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clearly sure what you need. But if you want identical children based on its position in another container with the same class you can try this way using `index(`) and `nth-child`. Also `on(hover)` is not valid it is a combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

See this example to select identical elements from other container with the same class.

```
$(function(){
     $('ul.features li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
             $('ul.features > li:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ' )').toggleClass('active');
       });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FdJ53/)

if you want to select all other but not the hovered one you can do this

```
 $('ul.features > li:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ' )').not(this).toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: @NicholasHazel  follow my edit. Your document ready syntax is in correct.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Your syntax is wrong, see my edit it should be $(function(){...});

Comment: No, you already have document ready. put this code inside that.

Comment: $(function(){ is same as document ready. but your code is wrong if you look closely.

Comment: Indeed it is.
One final question:
How would I apply a specific class to the very left li item?
ie: View the headings how they change color on column hover. I'd essentially like to style the left li the same way:

Here is my page for the example (ignore the other 3 lists, it's intentional)
http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/price.html

Comment: @NicholasHazel what class needs to be applied?

Comment: I went ahead and took care of it with:

$('ul.features > li.category:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ' )').toggleClass('pri_cat');

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS3 :nth-child() Selector :
see then link below

[Style Odd and Even](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)